# Is there a way to use ALTREP with Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

Example:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
size_t z1(SEXP x) {
  return Rf_xlength(x);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
size_t z2(NumericVector x) {
  // do anything or nothing
  return 1;
}
```

R:

```
x <- seq(1,1e10)
z1(x)
[1] 1e+10

z2(x)
# computer hard crash
```

Suppose as example, I just wanted to take the first 10 elements of an ALTREP vector.  What would be the best way to do so in C++?

Comment: This recent link might be appropriate: https://purrple.cat/blog/2018/10/14/altrep-and-cpp/

Comment: i) ALTREP is not released.  ii) You can look at ChangeLog and NEWS.Rd and scan for ALTREP.  There is nothing yet.  For why see i)  ;-)   Help welcome.  If you want to experiment, come to the rcpp-devel list and discuss.  Last time I met Gabe / talked to Gabe his view still was that package would not have to do all that much.  We'll see.  I guess it will be more of a topic in 2019.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I was wondering if you or Romain would jump in quickly. It's been a low-priority lingering question I've had but didn't have the need to ask (yet).

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding, but in the change log of R 3.5.0 it says "Arithmetic sequences created by 1:n, seq_along, and the like now use compact internal representations via the ALTREP framework. "  Doesn't that mean it is released?

Comment: @thc: In the narrow sense the answer is of course YES.  You can program anything you want with Rcpp.  But if your question really is "does Rcpp currently contain ALTREP-aware interfaces" then the answer is no, as you can tell from the Rcpp NEWS and ChangeLog.  As I said, likely in 2019. Or whenever someone (you?) starts on it.

Comment: Maybe, I'll have time to look at this next summer. If noone has work on it since.

Answer (score 2):

Rcpp is currently not ALTREP aware. The conversion from an ALTREP `SEXP` to `NumericVector` will therefore materialize it. In my case R stops telling me it cannot the allocate required memory, but that's a minor difference.

For now you have to handle ALTREP object without the niceties of Rcpp, for example for your final question:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP get_region(SEXP x, R_xlen_t i, R_xlen_t n) {
  SEXP result;
  switch (TYPEOF(x)) {
    case INTSXP: {
      result = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(INTSXP, n));
      INTEGER_GET_REGION(x, i, n, INTEGER(result));
      UNPROTECT(1);
      break;
    }
    case REALSXP: {
      result = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, n));
      REAL_GET_REGION(x, i, n, REAL(result));
      UNPROTECT(1);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      Rcpp::stop("Invalid SEXPTYPE %d (%s).\n", TYPEOF(x), Rcpp::type2name(x));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

/*** R
x <- seq(1,1e10)
.Internal(inspect(x)) # @5623ba0b65f0 14 REALSXP g0c0 [NAM(3)]  1 : 10000000000 (compact)
get_region(x, 0, 10)  # [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

x <- seq(1,1e9)
.Internal(inspect(x)) # @5623ba143ff0 13 INTSXP g0c0 [NAM(3)]  1 : 1000000000 (compact)
get_region(x, 0, 10)  # [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
*/
```

This uses run-time polymorphism from http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-wrap-and-recurse/.